# Erro no uso de @extends usando sass placeholders

Tags: css, sass, scss

```js
    @each $direction in $directions {
  %u-no-padding-#{$direction}{padding-#{direction}: 0;}
  %u-half-padding-#{$direction}{padding-#{direction}: $layout-module-size / 2;}
  %u-default-padding-#{$direction}{padding-#{direction}: $layout-module-size;}
  %u-double-padding-#{$direction}{padding-#{direction}: $layout-module-size * 2;}


  %u-no-margin-#{$direction}{margin-#{direction}: 0;}
  %u-half-margin-#{$direction}{margin-#{direction}: $layout-module-size / 2;}
  %u-default-margin-#{$direction}{margin-#{direction}: $layout-module-size;}
  %u-double-margin-#{$direction}{margin-#{direction}: $layout-module-size * 2;}
}

body{
  @extend %u-double-margin-top, %u-double-margin-bottom, %u-half-margin-bottom;
}
```

na compilação esta gerando o seguinte resultado

```js
body {
  margin-direction: 60px;
}

body {
  margin-direction: 15px;
}

body {
  margin-direction: 60px;
}
```

Alguém sabe como resolver esse problema? Preciso que o resultado gerado esteja dentro do mesmo body.